# Database First - MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Sempre trabalhei com code first e utilizando apenas um banco de dados. Porém, estou precisando trabalhar com uma aplicação com dois banco de dados já criados.

Para trabalhar com dois bancos de dados, criei isso:

Passando:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Recebendo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Agora, como posso trabalhar de forma fácil para reaproveitar a estrutura já existente dos bancos, inclusive as views ?

Comment: Depende do que você entende por reaproveitar. Os dois databases têm objetos em comum? Os dois databases têm objetos completamente diferentes?

Comment: Os dois objetos tem database completamente diferentes. 
Basicamente, em um eu tenho um acompanhamento financeiro com duplicatas e blablabla já no outro, eu tenho o pré-pedido que por intermédio a um ERP, vai gerar essas duplicatas.

Minha plataforma é de transações, é apenas para relatórios. Não vou ter nenhum método de exclusão/edição/adição. Portanto queria uma maneira simples de trabalhar as consultas nesses dois bancos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para contextos somente-leitura, adicione o seguinte na classe de contexto:

```
public override int SaveChanges()
{
    throw new AccessViolationException(
         "Contexto é somente leitura.");
}

public override async Task<int> SaveChanges()
{
    throw new AccessViolationException(
         "Contexto é somente leitura.");
}
```

Isto garante que o contexto não pode realizar modificações no banco de dados.

No mais, eu acho que você já está usando de acordo.